# Stack Overflow is offline

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, offline

I can't reach [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) any more. **Yesterday**, [the status blog said](https://www.stackstatus.net/):

> After our weekly index optimization, SQL Server is no longer caching our query plans causing high CPU load. This will likely overload our CPUs **tomorrow** if we don’t get this resolved.

Is this happening now?

Comment: Seems like it.  MSO is the only site I'm able to load.

Comment: Last update from [@StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus) was: *"StackExchange Status ‏@StackStatus 6h

#stackoverflow is now back online, we are continuing to work on the issue.*" - Nothing saying that the issue itself has been fixed. So no, looks like it's still an issue.

Comment: Don't know why this is getting downvotes. I'd say [it's pretty well borked](http://prntscr.com/26mhk3). And it's not recovering for me.

Comment: @JonW the blog post says *We are currently working with Microsoft to resolve this issue. **You may notice short outages while we troubleshoot**. We will do our best to minimize the impact*

Comment: I have no issues with [workplace.se], but stack overflow itself is not working.

Comment: @Emracool even Google or Facebook suffer outage from time to time, no site has 100% uptime. If this will go on for long time (hour or so) then we can start yelling here on Meta. :)

Comment: Stack Overflow should just report a stack overflow for teh lulz.

Comment: @Sha An ASPX error like that _usually_ doesn't recover on its own, as far as I've seen. That's indicative of a more serious error. I agree, though, maybe would have waited an hour or three before posting :]

Comment: Place your bets on how many more Meta StackOverflow posts get raised reporting this outage...

Comment: And there we go. [Now the site is **actually** borked.](http://prntscr.com/26mi5d)

Comment: I have no problem deleting this. Shall I?

Comment: @Emracool this kind of error just means there was error even in the error page, nothing too fancy or serious. If you would see *Stack Trace* then we got to start worrying. :)

Comment: @Emracool huh... the most offline I can get is the "we are offline" message

Comment: This happens more often these days compared to times before

Comment: @Emracool not offline, read only mode. There's a difference.

Comment: @Sha Whoops, edited. It's 1:30 here, cut me some slack ;]

Comment: @Emracool not my fault you live in San Diego! ;)

Comment: Well the meta site is not read only, and the chats too.

Comment: *This site is currently in read-only mode; we’ll return with full functionality soon.* - The exact message I'm getting and also none of the links are active, other than the *Careers 2.0*.

Comment: @juergend no, please don't delete we're having fun while the sites are doing roomba.

Comment: @juergen I'd leave this open if I were you; I'd probably make edit it to address the read-only issue specifically, though

Comment: @rekire different servers

Comment: @Bart I guessed that thank you for confirming that!

Comment: And its back now.

Comment: Wow, it appears to be fixed now. Is anyone still having problems, or can we close this as not reproducible?

Comment: it's working again

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We're playing SQL hot potato.  Today may be a tad... "fun" while we find the gremlins.

Looks like we're stable as I write this though.

Comment: Good luck guys. Hope you slove the problems soon!

Comment: @Kevin will it affect the ETA to deliver the new top bar across all sites?

Comment: If these problems will last a while, is it possible to put up a banner on the main page saying so? (Have fun! /grin)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - It is effecting all development. We will wait util we have a fix or we know enough to work around the issue.

Comment: @Oded it's still rev 2013.11.22.1677 - so will you put new build with those breaking changes rolled back? (to deploy all the bug fixes done in those last few days :))

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - The problem is with SQL Server. We can't roll back to a prior version of SQL Server.

Comment: @Oded true enough... good luck with that! :)