# Profile-hover-quick-view thingy isn't loading

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-card

For some reason, the profile-hover view thingy is not loading at all(on *Stackoverflow*). I initially thought that it might be because of [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208850/stack-overflow-is-offline), but its been closed with the status, *no-repro*. Also, this is now persisting for the past 1 hour for me.

I tried to clear the cache and stuffs but nothing seems to be working, as the hover view is still not loading. Is this some sort of [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or an issue with the browser? I'm using Firefox 25.0.1 on Win7 Pro(x86) machine. Here is a snapshot of it.

[image: Profile-hover-quick-view]

Comment: I have the same issue on Chrome 31.0.1650.57

Comment: It's gone for good on Meta, we have a [new top bar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207420/152859). Unless you mean something else not in the top bar?

Comment: Works fine on Chrom 31.0.1650.57 m on Win XP

Comment: Oh, you mean on Stack Overflow. Works fine for me, try capturing the request in network tab of Chrome console or just browse directly to http://stackoverflow.com/users/profile-link-stats - what you get?

Comment: I can reproduce it. Does not work for me either (I thought you meant something else before).

Comment: @juergend when you browse [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/profile-link-stats) what do you get?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: *Oops! Something Bad Happened!*

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Gives me data same as what I get when I hover on my profile name. And it's a new hidden feature!

Comment: @juergend what lolcat? j/k - well, we have the actual bug. Oh, just got "This site is currently in read-only mode" while posting this comment guess they're still [playing hot potato](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208853) with the SQL Server. :/

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Even I got that just now(on Meta) and refreshing it after 30 secs, it went back to normal. But that doesn't answer, why its not loading in SO.

Comment: This is also happening to me on Chromium 30.0.1599.114 on Linux Mint 13. (EDIT: Actually I was wrong - it happens on the Sci-fi and Fantasy SE site, but not on SO)

Comment: @R.J with database as big and complex as this any small hiccup can cause unexpected problems at unexpected places.

Comment: @hims056 enjoy the hidden feature as you can, it will soon vanish when new top bar is going network wide. (here on Meta the link always give error, we don't have the profile hover thingy here so they probably disabled the code behind as well :))

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Yeah I do understand that :) I'm just wondering, why wasn't Meta(or many other sites) unaffected when SO went down and why should this get affected when Meta went down(for a very small time). And I guess this should be gone forever, once the new top-var goes network wide, but then, there isn't a fixed date when its going live, is it?

Comment: @R.J think of a small ant eating its way through a tree. You can't tell the exact damage to the tree, but there is damage. The SQL bug is probably like that ant. As for top bar it was supposed to be today but postponed due to unexpected problems, not related to this SQL bug. My guess is two weeks at least. :)

Comment: @R.J Meta probably wasn't down because it's on separate hardware from the rest of the network. The SE staff has it on separate hardware so they can use it as a beta. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10370/197656

Comment: @JoshuaDwire - Well though the Meta was on a different hardware, but still a couple of users did see that error message, which means that there was atleast a minor glitch which was probably fixed almost immediately! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A fix is awaiting to be deployed, but currently on hold because of our current problems with SQL Server.

Please be patient :-)

---

We are now deploying to meta. It should not make a difference to anyone because the "thingy" is obsoleted by the new top bar.

---

The issue is fixed in meta, as verified by hitting the old routes manually. We're pushing live now, hold on to your socks!

---

Fix is deployed, thanks for your patience. I could not repro after the fix.

---

New fix for layout issues is on dev and will be out in the next push. *This addresses the comments below.*

Comment: Nice, I thought it was disabled on Meta as part of the new top bar.

Comment: Also, why it affected only part of the users? I got it working all along, on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Because it only appears without the top bar and with recent badges.

Comment: I got back my "reputation summary popup" But there are some alignment issues within it.  Take a look at this [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HvpyB.png)

Comment: I have tested in lasted version of FF and chrome, [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208865/profile-hover-quick-view-thingy-isnt-loading#comment667210_208875) happens.

Comment: Indeed. Status completed. But as @PraveenJeganathan mentioned, the recent badges alignment seems to be a problem now.

Comment: @R.J please see my last updated (fix for the alignment issue is done but queued up for deployment)

Comment: Yeah just saw! :) Thanks for getting stuffs done so quickly. Really appreciate the work from the devs! :) Unfortunately, can't upvote it more than once. :D

Answer (score 3):

I can reproduce the same issue on Chrome 31.0.1650.57 on OSX 10.9.

It looks like a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

[image]

As suggested by Sha Wiz Dow Ard in the comments, I tried to navigate to https://stackoverflow.com/users/profile-link-stats and it shows me an error page ("Oops! Something Bad Happened!")

I strongly suspect it's related to this: https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/68024017517/sql-performance-issues-november-24th-2013 and it will probably fix itself when that issue will be fully resolved.